# Java: Generics on data structures and wildcards

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, wildcard

I'm trying to learn how to use generics and for that, I'm creating my own data structure similar to a list with an Iterator and all.

The uppermost class is declared as:

```
public class BasicList<A> implements Iterable {
}
```

It's just a list with nodes and a single pointer to the next element.

There's another list, called DescendingList, that does pretty much the same, only this time around, you're getting another output since the Iterator is different. I'm giving a comparator to this List to get the Iterator to work. The comparator is just an interface:

```
public interface Bigger<A> {
    boolean bigger(A x);
}
```

DescendingList looks like this:

```
public class DescendingList<A extends Bigger<A>> extends BasicList<A> implements Iterable {
}
```

The idea is that it could work with any kind of object that is comparable through the Bigger interface.

Now I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Rock implements Bigger<Rock> {
}
```

And finally, a normal class which extends the Rock class:

```
public class Mineral extends Rock {
}
```

So, the issue at hand is that, while I can easily create a new BasicList filled with Minerals like this:

```
BasicList<Mineral> min = new BasicList<Mineral>();
```

I can't do the same with the DescendingList. Whenever I try going with

```
DescendingList<Mineral> min = new DescendingList<Mineral>();
```

my IDE (IntelliJ) goes all

```
"Type parameter "Rock" is not within it's bound; should implement Bigger<Mineral>"
```

And I don't really get why that happens. I am pretty sure that I've messed up the type parameters somehow and I'm really not sure where. This should be solveable somehow (at least without removing any classes/interfaces - the class headers might be and probably are completely messed up). Thanks in advance for any help you might offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Mineral` isn't a `Bigger<Mineral>`, it's a `Bigger<Rock>`, and that is incompatible with `Bigger<Mineral>`, because even though a `Mineral` is a `Rock`, Java's generics are invariant.  It needs to be a `Bigger<Rock>` because of how `Rock` is defined -- implementing `Bigger<Rock>` -- and that `DescendingList` declares type parameter `A` to be a `Bigger<A>`.

Because it's a consumer (type parameter as a method parameter), the type parameter `A` needs a lower-bound (super) on its declaration.

```
class DescendingList<A extends Bigger<? super A>> // ...
```

This way `Mineral` will be within its own bound.

As an aside, you are implementing the raw form of `Iterable` in `BasicList`; you should supply a type argument there.